# Calabash Android: how to send app to the background (simulate device/hardware Home button)?

Tags: android, automated-tests, homescreen, calabash

Is there a way in Calabash Android where I can send my app to the background? In other words, simulate the device/hardware Home button?

Secondly, can the app be brought back into the foreground?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in the following way:

```
Then /^I go home$/ do
  system "#{default_device.adb_command} shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME"
end
```

P.S. You can also add `sleep <some_value_in_seconds>` if necessary, after `system "..."` line.

Comment: I advice also to read http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/.

You can use `keyboard_enter_keyevent` method from there. So it will be as `keyboard_enter_keyevent('KEYCODE_HOME')`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that action does not currently exist.  You can find (mostly) all of the available operations here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/tree/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android.  Most of the interesting options are in the operations.rb file.  The performAction method would be the method most likely to help you as it has a 'go_back' and 'press_menu' feature, but currently no 'go_home' feature.  When you're in a calabsh console, you can type performAction 'list_actions' to see all possible actions.  I'm not sure if it's a reasonable workaround, but you could try something like this:

```
until (query "*").empty? do
  performAction 'go_back'
end
```

This will sipmly press the back button until you've arrived on the home screen.  If you'd like to get back to your app, however, you'd need to re-run `start_test_server_in_background` as you will not be able to get any query information from the home screen.  Anyways, good luck and I hope I could help out at least a little!