# Calabash-android: How can I simulate device home button for calabash-android

Tags: calabash-android

I am using system("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME") to simulate the home button in calabash-android, my test fails for my next step.As per my app functionality when the relaunch the app from the background it displays with the pin screen,which i am not able to get it with the KEYCODE_HOME. However it works with the KEYCODE_BACK.

Please help me out for the simulation for the home button.

Comment: try this `press_button('KEYCODE_HOME')`

Comment: it doesn't work for me..and i don't see any test fail as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393894/calabash-android-how-to-send-app-to-the-background-simulate-device-hardware-ho) which was provided from a previous user of the same question.